# send email to user also who is inputting his/her details in php

Tags: php, email

I am able to send emails to the $to fields but i have to send email to the user also that his submission has been received.
i have to send email to $_POST["email"]

here is the code

```
<?php

 $ToEmail = 'abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com';
 $EmailSubject = 'Successfull Contact Form Submission';
 $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
 $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
 $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["fname"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Company: ".$_POST["company"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Address: ".$_POST["address"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "City: ".$_POST["city"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "State: ".$_POST["state"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Zip: ".$_POST["zip"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Fax: ".$_POST["fax"]."\r\n";
 $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["message"])."\r\n";
 mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
 ?>
```

Comment: So as i understand you just need to add that email to to field?
`$ToEmail = 'abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com,' . $_POST['email'];`

Comment: Your going to want to add more validation & filtering to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use th Cc header or even Bcc:

```
$mailheader = "Cc: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
```

or

```
$mailheader = "Bcc: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrong camelcase. You have to use first letter camelcase  only for classes.

> ```
> $toEmails[] = 'abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com';
> $toEmails[] = $_POST['email'];
>
> (...)
>
> foreach ($toEmails as $email) {
>      mail($email, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die('Failure');    
> }
> ```

But die() on error is wrong way. Better catch error to exception and continue script running with correct emails.